# How to implement a gridview that has albums which displays image previews

Tags: android, gridview

How to implement a gridview that has albums  which displays image previews(previews of images that the specific album contains ) ?

This is for a image gallery app.i searched for like 4 hours i can't find a way to do this. But most of gallery  apps have this feature

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter when you get the view, you need validate that the element is a directory and contains images, then you get an image recursively. Is too simple do it.

This is my code for get an image from folder recursively, return the first image found. See [FileFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter.html)!

```
  private File searchThumbnail(File folder) {
    File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FilterGallery());
    if (files != null)
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory())
                return searchThumbnail(file);
            else
                return file;
        }
    return null;
  }
```